# How to fix the conflict in the naming scheme for network interfaces use by Predictable Names scheme?

Tags: debian, networking, scripting, network-interface, udev

I have a fresh install of Debian 10 (Buster) and there is an issue with the Predictable Name scheme.

I have 4 onboard NICs and a 4 Port PCIe NIC.

The naming convention works for the onboard port, but the 4 Port PCIe works for the first 2 ports correctly `ens2f1` & `ens2f0` but the last 2 have the names `rename8` and `rename9`.

I read over this entire article here: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames

I understand why they got those names, here is a brief explanation:
Due to the priority used by the rules file `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` in `ID_NET_NAME` my names for these interfaces are coming from `ID_NET_NAME_SLOT`, the issue is that the `_SLOT` is the same for `ens2f0` and `rename8`, likewise for the `ens2f1` and `rename9` when testing with `udevadm`
Here is the output for `ens2f0` and `rename8`:

```
# udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/ens2f0 2>/dev/null
ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v240
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx00151757e989
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporate
ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp13s0f0
ID_NET_NAME_SLOT=ens2f0

# udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/rename8 2>/dev/null
ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v240
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx00151757e98b
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporate
ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp14s0f0
ID_NET_NAME_SLOT=ens2f0
```

1. **Can I just override the `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` file and make it use the `ID_NET_NAME_PATH`?**
   Changing this line:
   `NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME}"`
   To
   `NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}"`
2. **How would I override this file, where would I put the new rules file, since in the file it says "do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update"?**

I am pretty sure I grasp an understanding of how this "script" works.
In this line `NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME}"`, it first checks if `NAME` is equal to `""`, then makes sure the `ENV{ID_NET_NAME}` is not equal to `""`, and then it sets a new `NAME` based on the `ID_NET_NAME` priority.

Here is the complete file I have (I know it must be the same for everyone, but for clarity I am posting it):

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update

SUBSYSTEM!="net", GOTO="net_setup_link_end"

IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"

ACTION!="add", GOTO="net_setup_link_end"

IMPORT{builtin}="net_setup_link"

NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME}"

LABEL="net_setup_link_end"
```

3. **Could I change it too look something like this?**

```
SUBSYSTEM!="net", GOTO="net_setup_link_end"

IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"

ACTION!="add", GOTO="net_setup_link_end"

IMPORT{builtin}="net_setup_link"

NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}"
NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_SLOT}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_SLOT}"
NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_MAC}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_MAC}"
NAME=="", ENV{ID_NET_NAME}!="", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME}"

LABEL="net_setup_link_end"
```

Comment: So I am mainly just looking for an answer to #4 now. I might edit this question to remove #4 and answer the question with what I found out and ask #4 in a separate question, but I will give time for others to view this before doing that unless I am advised otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can change it to use `ID_NET_NAME_PATH` specifically and not just `ID_NET_NAME` priority.
2. Override file goes here: `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`
3. Yes, that script will work (Self-Tested)
4. Was moved to new question: [Checking if network interface name already exists in udev Predictable Names scheme rules?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611860)